# PHP loop with seperate table

Tags: php, html

How do i sperate the data with different table ,i need show all my data with loop but 'Bundle Name' of column same will with one table .

PHP code:

```
<table>
<?php
include('connection.php');

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bundel ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    echo $row['BundelName'];
    $bundel = $row['BundelName'];

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row['SKU'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row['Description'] ;
    echo '<td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    
    if ($row['BundelName'] != $bundel){
        echo"</table><br><br><table>";
    } 

}
?>
</table>
```

[image: MySQL]
[image: My result]

[image: my expected result]

Comment: I would store db response in array variable. Do grouping in php and then draw table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to parse the results using a single loop, the following approach is an option. The important part here is that you need an `ORDER BY` clause in your statement and appropriate changes in the script, to make your loop work.

A simplified example, based on the code in the question:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bundel ORDER BY BundelName");
$bundel = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    if ($bundel != $row["BundelName"]) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row['BundelName'] . '</td></tr>';
    };

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Description'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['SalesPrice'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    if ($bundel != $row["BundelName"]) {
        echo "</table>";
        $bundel = $row["BundelName"];
    };
}
```

Of course, you can group and store the result set in an array using `BundelName` as key, and print the expected output using another loop:

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bundel");
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
    $result[$row["BundleName"]][] = array(
        "Description" => $row["Description"],
        "SalePrice" => $row["SalePrice"]
    );  
}

foreach ($result as $bundel => $products) {
    echo "<table>"; 
    echo '<tr><td>' . $bundel . '</td></tr>';
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $product["Description"] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $product["SalePrice"] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo"</table>";     
}
```

Comment: That one is a good solution. I use this way in my projects sometimes.

Comment: im intrest the group method ,how about i also need output my sell price and cost price ?sorry i not expert on php .@Zhorov

Comment: @nzxy12 The answer is updated. If you need more columns simply use a nested array.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend the way @Robert suggested.

But here is a quick and a dirty way to do this.

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT BundleName FROM bundel ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
      echo $row['BundelName'];
      $bundel=$row['BundelName'];
      echo"<table>";
      $query2 = "SELECT * FROM bundel WHERE BundelName='$bundel'";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
      while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td>';
             echo $row2['SKU'];
             echo '</td>';
             echo '<td>';
             echo $row2['Description'] ;
             echo '<td>';
             echo '</tr>';
        }
    echo"</table>";
                           
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'GROUP BY BundelName' in your sql query or you can first query 'SELECT DISTINCT(BundelName) FROM bundel ' and store in an array and use all distinct values of this array in creating separate tables. In group by case you can do a trick by creating a new table whenever you detect a new group in the while loop. Hint- in_array() in php.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer array_map or foreach but use "while" like on your example, try that:

```
    $results = [];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
      
      $results[$row['BundelName']] = $row['description'];

    }
```

And create table in html with data send by PHP.